# альтернатива константам для типов

Tags: typescript, redux

почему вместо этого(встречал во всех проектах)

```
export const LOAD_PHOTOS = 'LOAD_PHOTOS'
export const LOAD_CARDS = 'LOAD_CARDS'
export const SHOW = 'SHOW'
export const HIDE = 'HIDE'
```

не использовать вот это как по мне более элегантное решение

```
export enum MyTypes{
    LOAD_PHOTOS = 'LOAD_PHOTOS',
    LOAD_CARDS = 'LOAD_CARDS',
    SHOW = 'SHOW',
    HIDE = 'HIDE'
}
```

Comment: Возможно код был изначально на js и это артефакты переноса

Comment: К тому де эти константы, судя по названиям, должны быть в двух или трёх разных Enum-ах. Т.е. уже нужно думать и вводить новые сущности.

Comment: @AlexeyTen про артефакты переноса не знаю но это стандартное описание типов в redux приложениях... некий шаблон который идет из проекта в проект

Comment: @AlexeyTen нее это типы для одного редюсера

Comment: Ну тогда может просто «так повелось». Я вот не вижу особых плюсов в enum в этом месте. Разве что const enum для уменьшения рантайма, да и то сомнительно

Comment: @AlexeyTen плюсы появляются когда указываеш возврашаемый тип в экшанах или в редюсере вместо того чтобы описать что то типо {type:typeof SHOW } указываеш {type:MyTypes.SHOW } а для экшана в редюсере не тип собранный из A | B | C а просто MyTypes